# Typescript how to use optional chaining

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Why an i getting an error on this value assignment;

```
state.user?.weight.budget = budget;
```

[image]

I have tried a couple this like this

```
(state.user?.weight.budget ?? 0) = budget;
```

That doesn't work either. What an I doing wrong. I dont get it

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional chaining does [not support](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining#not-supported) assignment.  The feature was [discussed](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/18) but they decided it was out of scope for the initial proposal and that it might be implemented "later".  See [this comment](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/18#issuecomment-343926065) in particular.

Your latter example, `(state.user?.weight.budget ?? 0) = budget;` also won't work because not only are you trying to do an optional chaining assignment, but you're also trying to assign to an expression that is possibly not a variable or the property of a variable (`0 = budget`?).

For now, the only way to do an assignment in the presence of possibly-undefined `user` property is via control flow without optional chaining, like this:

```
if (state.user != null) state.user.weight.budget = budget;
```

or some equivalent test-and-maybe-assign code.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.9.2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3pqGQC54BvAKHnIoFc0QYB+Q0i5lgdxAEsBzACw0bIshQgEaVgXEP3gpKAWxG0A3IOEUAvvFUaS6kqEiwEydFjESphWQuUkSAenvYMuEADpqtOm-bc+b80ksAF54QKkVEg4AM3gAChw8DxoYeABCUNkICABKZ1dk2h9OXgwA8SD4UPCMJSA)